# can anyone provide me with Java code to generate timestamp to be used in OAuth requests?

Tags: java, android, http, oauth, timestamp

The OAuth Spec says that **the timestamp is expressed in the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT.**
The timestamp value **MUST be a positive integer** and MUST be equal or greater than the timestamp used in previous requests.

I need it to us it my Android App to make an http post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for the current time stamp use `System.currentTimeMillis()/1000`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
int authSeconds = (int)(new Date().getTime()/1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
int authSeconds = (int)(new Date().getTime()/1000);
```